Can I start a bounty twice for the same question?
I have a question here for bounty and apparantely nobody is bothering to answer.Can I start a bounty again for the same question?

Did you just call me a nobody? :(

Hey, I didn't mean like that. I didn't get the required answer. I'm sorry @CurveEnthusiast

I was just joking! I hope you get the answer you want.

In my experience, bounties do not work well on crypto.stackexchange.com. Perhaps linking to the question in The Side Channel could help just as well..

Yes.
Quoting from the help-center:

Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
  minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
  the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
  so on).

